# Texdoc can't find some packages

Tags: texmf, texdoc

I'm trying to open some manuals with `texdoc`. Some of them `texdoc` can find and open, but others, even if installed, are invisible to `texdoc`.

```sh
$ locate soul.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/generic/soul/soul.pdf
$ locate xcolor.pdf
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/xcolor/xcolor.pdf
$ texdoc -l soul
 1 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/soul/soul.pdf
 2 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/generic/soul/soul.txt
Enter number of file to view, RET to view 1, anything else to skip:
$ texdoc -l xcolor
Sorry, no documentation found for "xcolor".
If you are unsure about the name, try full-text searching on CTAN.
Search form: <https://www.ctan.org/search/>
```

Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

I am running **Linux Mint 21.2**. And yes, documentation is installed as you can see by the result of the locate command.

Comment: just  guess, but seems one of two, or (1) locate show information  of the last `updatedb`, but it is outdated  (you can really see  xcolor.pdf with the file manager and open it with some pdfviewer?), or  (2) texdoc have no access to  directory or file (search path is correct? `ls -l`  show the right owner, groups and rights ? )

Comment: Note how the paths are different? Do you have two latex installations? And thus yexdoc looking in the wrong one

Comment: @Fran, **(1)** i have updated db with `sudo updatedb` before run these commands. And yes, i can open both with qpdfview (or any other pdfviewer). **(2)** probably this is the issue or, maybe, texdoc is not instructed to look in there. And both xcolor.pdf and soul.pdf are root:root and 644. Also, both directories **generic** and **latex** are root:root and 755.

Comment: @daleif, no, just one installation.

Answer (score 1):

**I found the problem and found the solution.** Thanks to @Fran and @daleif for helping.

The problem is that the documentation was installed after installing the **texlive** package. Apparently `texdoc` has a mechanism similar to the `locate` command, which needs to be updated with `sudo updatedb`. The difference is that the `locate` command's database is automatically updated after a reboot (or something like that), but `texdoc` does not.

I discovered this after uninstalling the **texlive** package (which also uninstalled some dependencies), and reinstalling texlive and its dependencies again. After that I was able to locate and open **xcolor.pdf** with `texdoc`.

```sh
$ sudo apt purge texlive
$ sudo apt install texlive asciidoc-dblatex dblatex dblatex-doc fonts-gfs-baskerville fonts-gfs-porson texlive-bibtex-extra texlive-lang-greek texlive-science
```

During installation, I noticed that it ran the following command:

```
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf... done.
```

With that I discovered the command needed to update the `texdoc` database!

```
$ sudo mktexlsr
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Done.
```

Comment: The job of `mktexlsr` is not only to texdoc benefits.  If really it had not been done (which looks like a distro bug) automatically after installing texlive then probably many other things could have gone wrong in everyday TeX/LaTeX/ etc... usage